# Mesh deforming when weight painting

Tags: weight-painting

I'm kinda new to blender and for some reason I'm having trouble weight painting my sculpted character. whenever I paint on it, it's as if I was still in sculpt mode and the mesh deforms. any tips?

Comment: Do you have armature deform modifier?

Comment: No I didn't but somehow it works now, thank you anyway